# removing duplicates from a c++ list

Tags: c++

I have been looking for an effective solution to remove duplicates from a C++ list.

The list consists of pointers to a class object which has an attribute ID. I want to remove duplicates based on that ID.

for my purpose, the unique method of the STL list will work in which we can pass a BinaryPredicate. i.e.

void unique( BinPred pr );

I searched on the internet about how to use this method, n got an example in which we can declare a function returning boolean and use the "name" of that function as Binary Predicate.

But it's not working.

What actually is this binary predicate and how do i use it ? ... 
Any help will be appreciated.
Here is the code snippet:

```
class SP_MDI_View {
..
..
bool removeDupli(SP_DS_Node*, SP_DS_Node*);
bool DoReductionGSPN(SP_DS_Node*, SP_ListNode*, SP_DS_Node*);
..
..
}
SP_MDI_View::DoReduction( ... ) {
 SP_ListNode setZ; // typedef list<SP_DS_Node*> SP_ListNode, where SP_DS_Node is some other class
 setZ.clear();
 setZ.merge(tempsubset);
 setZ.merge(setX);
 setZ.push_back(*cs_iter);
 setZ.unique(removeDupli); //Error here
}
bool SP_MDI_View::removeDupli(SP_DS_Node* first, SP_DS_Node* second) {
return ( (first->GetId())==(second->GetId()) );
}
```

Comment: This is the link which has the example i was talking about:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/unique/

is this valid?
mylist.unique (same_integral_part);

my compiler is not taking it as a valid statement.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?  Compile error?  Segfault?

Comment: post **your** code, is that a member function? what's the scope?

Comment: @SoapBox: The error is no matching function for call to 'std::list<SP_DS_Node*, std::allocator<SP_DS_Node*>>::unique(<unknown type>)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function like:

```
bool foo (int first, int second)
{ return (first)==(second) ); }
```

Also, you might need to declare the function as static if your using it in class.

Comment: yes i tried doing it. then i did

mylist.unique(foo);
but the compiler says no matching function unique.

Comment: I have posted the source code above. Static thing says "cannot declare member function to have static linkage"

Comment: @Gaurav: `static` should only appear in the class declaration, not when defining the member function out-of-class.

Comment: Hey that worked! ... But I still have duplicates in the list ... Do I need to sort the list first ?

Comment: yes we need to :-) ... everything is now working as expected! ... thanks a lot @Georg and @Dave

Answer (score 0):

You have to use unique on an **ordered list**. So the first thing that you must do is sort the list.

Comment: while sorting also, i have an overloaded sort function which uses binary predicate. the way am doing sort is: define a boolean function, use that as binary predicate. But it doesn't work.

is this valid ?
mylist.sort(same_integral_part);
i mean same_integral_part is a function and we are passing it as same_integral_part ?